# Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

When I upgrade React Native I received the error "Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART`"

Old version: `react-native: 0.60.5`

New version: `react-native: ^0.62.1`

npm version: `6.4.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ART was extracted from core react-native as a part of "Lean Core" effort.

```
npm install @react-native-community/art --save
import {Surface, Shape} from '@react-native-community/art';
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/art